# Fastest way to set elements of Pandas Dataframe based on a function with index and column value as input

Tags: pandas, dataframe, elementwise-operations

I have a single column Pandas dataframe:

```
s = 
      VALUE
INDEX
A     12
B     21
C     7
...
Y     21
Z     7
```

I want to make it into a square matrix mask with the same index and columns as `s.index`, with each element either `True` if the value of column and index are the same in `s` or `False` otherwise.

```
mask = 
      A     B     C ...      Y     Z 
A  True False False ...  False False
B False  True False ...   True False
C False False  True ...  False  True
...
Y False  True False ...   True False
Z False False  True ...  False  True
```

My actual `s` has 10K+ rows. What is the fastest way to generate that `mask` DataFrame?

One way I've tried is to create a 2-level dictionary with two `for` loops. (eg. `dict['A']['B'] = dict['B']['A'] = True if s.loc['A'] == s.loc['B'] else False`, etc.). Then convert bottom level of `dict` to a Pandas Series (eg. `row = pd.Series(dict[A])`), then append that series to `mask`. `mask` is constructed iteratively row by row.

That takes really long time, and has to explicitly loop through 10K x 10K / 2 = 50M elements... Not ideal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy` broadcasting

```
v = s.VALUE.values
pd.DataFrame(v == v[:, None], s.index, s.index)

INDEX      A      B      C      Y      Z
INDEX                                   
A       True  False  False  False  False
B      False   True  False   True  False
C      False  False   True  False   True
Y      False   True  False   True  False
Z      False  False   True  False   True
```